# Unable to take production build in angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular5

I'm using angular 2 base template.Later i have updated angular versions to 5 and cli to 1.6.5. I used some external 3rd party packages for my requirement. so while taking production build i'm facing some issues.
can anyone help me to sort out this issue.

so while taking production build this is the error i'm getting.

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'FancyImageUploaderModule'
>     Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'
>       'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.
>   node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable'.
>     Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
>       Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.
>         Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>           Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
>   node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts(24,22): error TS2415: Class 'WebSocketSubject' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject'.
>     Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
>       Type '(operator: Operator) => WebSocketSubject' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.
>         Type 'WebSocketSubject' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>           Types of property 'operator' are incompatible.
>             Type 'Operator' is not assignable to type 'Operator'.
>               Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1689,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1766,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1842,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.

This is my package.json file.

```
{
 "name": "CoreUI",
 "version": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
 "description": "Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template",
 "author": "",
 "url": "http://coreui.io",
 "copyright": "Copyright 2017 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
 "license": "MIT",
 "angular-cli": {},
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/common": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/core": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/forms": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/http": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/router": "^5.2.2",
   "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
   "angular-split": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
   "angular2-fontawesome": "^0.9.3",
   "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
   "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.2.1",
   "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
   "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
   "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
   "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.10.0",
   "core-js": "2.4.1",
   "e-ngx-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
   "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
   "lodash": "^4.17.11",
   "moment": "2.17.1",
   "mydatepicker": "^2.6.1",
   "mydaterangepicker": "^4.2.1",
   "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
   "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
   "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.0",
   "ng2-drag-drop": "^3.0.2",
   "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
   "ng2-fancy-image-uploader": "^2.0.1",
   "ng2-split": "^0.1.6",
   "ng2-split-pane": "^1.4.0",
   "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
   "ngx-chips": "^1.6.7",
   "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
   "ngx-quill": "^3.4.0",
   "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
   "ngx-toggle-switch": "^1.3.9",
   "rxjs": "5.2.0",
   "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
   "zone.js": "0.7.2"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.2",
   "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
   "@types/lodash": "^4.14.123",
   "@types/node": "7.0.8",
   "codelyzer": "2.0.1",
   "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
   "karma": "1.5.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
   "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.3.0",
   "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
   "protractor": "5.1.1",
   "ts-node": "2.1.0",
   "tslint": "4.5.1",
   "typescript": "^2.6.2"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add any text content as text rather than as an image. It's impossible to copy the text, requires less bandwidth and always available ;)

Comment: What you  saying? sorry not understandable

Comment: Please replace the image with quoted text in the question.

Comment: @phuzi I have changed